# Is there an inconsistency regarding Kilgrave's powers' duration?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, jessica-jones-2015, jessica-jones

In *Jessica Jones* (Netflix), Jessica states that Kilgrave's influence on someone doesn't last more than 10-12 hours, after which he needs to "renew" it (Season 1, Ep. 4, when talking about Easterns).

Yet, we discover in Ep. 5 that the "spy" taking pictures of Jessica for Kilgrave meets with him every *day*, at 10:00 am sharp. That's 24 hours: how does Kilgrave maintain the influence on his spy?

Comment: Jessica confronts him (the spy) over this problem. Kilgrave used his power to get the guy hooked on drugs, and became his supplier, which is why the spy kept coming back after the effect wore off.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is addressed in the show. Kilgrave hooked Malcolm on addictive drugs so that he could control him in the absence of his mind-control. For much of the time, Malcolm was largely free of *direct* control, but still very much in thrall to his drug pusher.

> **MALCOLM:** *I took pictures of you.*
>
> **JESSICA:** *Because he made you.*
>
> **MALCOLM:** *Sometimes I did it just for the drugs. Think about it. I met him once a day. Ten a.m. His controls don't last that long. You
> know they don't.*
>
> **JESSICA:** *That's why he got you hooked. So you would show up.*
>
> <sub><sup>[AKA The Sandwich Saved Me](https://genius.com/Jessica-jones-aka-the-sandwich-saved-me-annotated)</sup></sub>

Comment: Oh. That makes sense now -- I am not at that point of the show yet. A followup question then: why didn't Jessica wonder about that herself? She seems perfectly happy about the assumptions that (a) he is always under influence and (b) he only meets Kilgrave once a day. (I guess the answer to that would be "she figured out, but didn't see the point of stating that explicitly to Trish or the audience).

Comment: @ClementC. - At this point she isn't clear about the extent of his powers, nor how often he meets with Malcolm.

Comment: For the first point: again, with Easterns, she appears very positive Kikgrave's influence vanished after 10-12h, positive enough to argue Easterns was not under control. But I reckon I'll learn more as I watch the remaining episodes - at this point, so many things still haven't been revealed.